# How to split up the command here for using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, command, subprocess

```
ip = subprocess.Popen(["/sbin/ifconfig $(/sbin/route | awk '/default/ {print $8}') | grep \"inet addr\" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk \'{print $1}\'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am not sure where to put the commas to separate them to use this command using subprocess.Popen. Does anyone know?

Comment: Use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).

Comment: how exactly is that to be used?

Comment: Just import the module and do `shlex.split('your long command')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would recommend.

Create a file with this contents - call it 'route-info' and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/ifconfig $(/sbin/route | awk '/default/ {print $8}') |
    grep "inet addr" |
    awk -F: '{print $2}' |
    awk '{print $1}'
```

In your python program, use:

```
ip = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/route-info"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then you don't have to worry about quoting characters and you can independently test the `route-info` script to make sure it is working correctly.

The script `route-info` doesn't take any command line arguments, but if it did this is how you would pass them:

```
ip = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/route-info", arg1, arg2, ...], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Super! Saved my day. Could you also tell me what would work on Mac and how this route-info can distinguish Mac from the above that I am going to use for CentOS?

Comment: To find the default route on OSX, use `route -n get default`. I think you should just create specific versions for each OS and install the correct one when you install the script - i.e. determine the OS at install time, not at run time.

Comment: This is just a silly cumbersome inelegant workaround for those who could not understand tdelaney's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are using shell features (the pipe) so instead of splitting the command, you should pass it as a single string (not a list) with `shell=True`

```
ip = subprocess.Popen("/sbin/ifconfig $(/sbin/route | awk '/default/ {print $8}') | grep \"inet addr\" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk \'{print $1}\'",
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: gonna have to try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the official documentation of `subprocess.Popen` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

> It may not be obvious how to break a shell command into a sequence of
> arguments, especially in complex cases. shlex.split() can illustrate
> how to determine the correct tokenization for args:
>
> ```
> import shlex, subprocess
> command_line = input()
>
> args = shlex.split(command_line)
> print(args)
>
> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
> ```

[shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) is included in standard library so you need not to install it.

Writing it in a single line like `str.split()` should look like:

```
import shlex
import subprocess 

command = "ls -l"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command) , stdout = subprocess.PIPE , stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
output , errors = proc.communicate()
print(output , errors)
```